# Class associated method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am new to MVC, my issue is a concern that I have not gone about this the right way, it currently works how I expect but I am unsure about the structure and where to put the method.

I have a class that I am using to help display to the view (a view model?) called `FolderFileList`, it also contains a function called `GetFolderStructure()`, this function takes a path and a folder and loops through creating a list of all the files and folders, then returns them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace xxx.Models
{

    public class FolderFileList
    {
        public DirectoryInfo Directory { get; set; }
        public FileInfo File { get; set; }

        public List<FileInfo> FileList { get; set; }
        public List<DirectoryInfo> FolderList { get; set; }
        public List<DirectoryInfo> RootFolderList { get; set; }
        public string FolderRoot { get; set; 
    }


    public static FolderFileList GetFolderStructure(string path, string foldername)
    {
        //initialise variables
        DirectoryInfo selecteddirectory = null;
        DirectoryInfo rootdirectory = null;
        var files = new List<FileInfo>();

        var listoffilesandfolders = new FolderFileList();
        listoffilesandfolders.FileList = new List<FileInfo>();
        listoffilesandfolders.FolderList = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
        listoffilesandfolders.RootFolderList = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
        listoffilesandfolders.FolderRoot = foldername;

        //get selected directory
        try
        {
            selecteddirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path + foldername);
            listoffilesandfolders.FolderList = selecteddirectory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not open the directory", exp);
        }
        catch (IOException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to access directory", exp);
        }

        //get root directory
        try
        {
            rootdirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            listoffilesandfolders.RootFolderList = rootdirectory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not open the directory", exp);
        }
        catch (IOException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to access directory", exp);
        }

        //get all files and subfolder files
        try
        {
            files = selecteddirectory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find file", exp);
        }
        catch (IOException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to access fie", exp);
        }

        files = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            listoffilesandfolders.FileList.Add(file);
        }

        return listoffilesandfolders;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult Folder(string foldername)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath(@"~\");

        var folderstructure = FolderFileList.GetFolderStructure(path, foldername);


        return View(folderstructure);

    }
```

My questions are:

1. Where do I put this class? It is currently in the model folder.
2. The method is dependent on the class, is it ok to have it in the class? What should I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question number one:

Personally, I would create a folder called "ViewModels" or "Classes." It's really up to you. If you move the class you should update the Namespace in the code.

Number 2: You can house the method in the ViewModel. As mentioned below by StewartLC now the view can call that method and you may not want that. If not, I would put it in the controller.

Comment: The problem with passing `FolderFileList` as a ViewModel to the View, is that the View can now call `GetFolderStructure` to interrogate a drive - arguably not a presentation concern.

Comment: StuartLC, that's a good point. Should a model passed to a view only have properties and no methods?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for guiding my in the right direction, I moved the class into a ViewModel, I then took out the Method and put it into a service class.